# How do I implement Ruby's ".each" method in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, loops, for-loop, each

I'm new to Java and wondering how I could go about implementing a method like Ruby's `.each` to make iterating over classes like Arrays and Lists easier?

Comment: There are a number of implementations, but they're all bulky because of the need to create an interface implementation. Until Java 8's closures, you should evaluate if they're really what you want. They can make sense if you compose a lot of concrete functors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an each function, like Ruby has, since Java doesn't accept blocks as parameters like Ruby does.  You could use an interface and provide an anonymous class definition, but that's way more complicated than just using Java's for each construct.  To do for each in Java, you can do something like the following:

```
String[] myStrings = { "a", "b", "c" };

for (String str : myStrings) {
    // Do something with each String value.
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: OK.  I had a hunch it might not be possible.  I was really trying to get around having to write the full syntax for a `for` loop.

Comment: To be completely honest, the boilerplate code is not too much greater; the only difference (in terms of verbosity) is that you have to specify the type.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  Just writing java Everything thing seems so much more verbose.  I'm picking this as the right answer because it's the most sane thing to do.  thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4):

While it is true that it's slightly awkward to achieve in standard Java, a couple of the popular libraries (that you may even already be using) offer a `Predicate` interface that spares you the bulk of writing that much, at least. The great thing is that they also offer thoroughly-tested, proven helper classes that mean **you don't have to write the iteration code**.

Check out Google Guava's [Iterables](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) class - you can do things like `filter()`, `findIf()` and `removeIf()`. If used well, these methods can make for extremely readable results.

Apache's Commons Collections offers something similar in [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html). Methods like `find()`, `filter()` and `select()` all take a `Predicate`.

Google Guava also goes further and gives you the `Predicates` helper which has a [whole load](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) of canned `Predicate` instances - things like `isNull`, `containsPattern` and `isInstanceOf`.

Check them out if you want to avoid reinventing the wheel for this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It gets ugly due to the lack of closures, until Java 8, but here it is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


public class EachTest {

    interface ItemProcessor<T>{
        void process(T item);
    }

     static <T> void each(Collection<T> collection, ItemProcessor<T> processor){
        for (T item: collection){
            processor.process(item);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list=Arrays.asList(new String("foo"),"bar");

        EachTest.<String>each(list,new ItemProcessor<String>() {
            @Override
            public void process(String item) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I think in Java 8, it will be (but don't quote me on that):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList(new String("foo"),"bar");
    EachTest.<String>each(list,String item=>System.out.println(item));
}
```

Comment: I think as of last week that would be `->` instead of `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) or you can do it with a special version of for:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = ...;

for (String str : strings) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the command pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Java